# How do I fix my GET request to an api using R's httr package

Tags: r, httr

I am trying to get data from an api for a data science project. The code below is the GET request that I used and it's giving me an error. Please let me know how to fix this error.

This is the code I wrote:

```
library(httr)

url <- "https://netflix-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com/api/search"

queryString <- list(year = "2020")

response <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers(x_rapidapi-key = 'MY_KEY', x_rapidapi-host = 'netflix-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com', '), query = queryString, content_type("application/octet-stream"))

content(response, "text")
```

this is the error I am getting:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "response <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers(x_rapidapi-key ="
```

Comment: Try `response <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers(x_rapidapi-key = 'a496701a12mshcc81289a5030e17p16e800jsn620ebcf4c9e4', x_rapidapi-host = 'netflix-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com'), query = queryString, content_type("application/octet-stream"))` You have an extra `, '` in there

Comment: You probably don't want to put your API key on the internet. You also have multiple typos, including the ones already pointed out, as well as invalid names like "x_rapidapi-key". When I get an error like that, I assume there's a typo

Comment: Okay, it's working. Thanks to you both